# Access control origin error for axios get method

Tags: django, firefox, react-redux

I am trying to communicate my front end to back end, but I am keep on getting in firefox

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://127.0.0.1:8000/getBikeParkingDetailsFromDb. (Reason: header ‘access-control-allow-origin’ is not allowed according to header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’ from CORS preflight response).
```

I added below cors headers in my request also,

```
 const options = {
        headers : { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'},
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/getBikeParkingDetailsFromDb',
        method:'get'
    }
    
    try {
        let posts = await axios(options)
        console.log(posts)
        dispatch(fetchPostsSuccess(posts) )
    }
    catch(e){
        console.log(e)
    }
```

and in my back end (django) I added below lines in settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [

    'corsheaders',

    #rest apps
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:3000",
]
```

added response headers as well

```
def get_bike_parking_details(request):
    all_bike_details = BikeParkingInfo.objects.all()
    serialize_data = serializers.serialize('json', all_bike_details)
    response = HttpResponse(serialize_data, content_type="text/json")
    response['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    response['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = '*'
    return response
```

but I am still facing same issue, currently I have used extension in chrome to make it work end to end, but need to find solution for this

Update:1

after keeping just

```
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
```

works in my firefox but not in chrome..any idea?

Comment: Use either `CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS ` or `CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS`.  Have you also tried `pip install --upgrade django-cors-headers` ?

Comment: sorry I think you pasted same option twice? CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS, and ya I installed django cors headers today

Comment: Yes i meant `CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS `

Comment: Well I tried both first I kept just all origins =True that didn't work, so added another as well

Comment: Just to add one more thing, I saw my back end response was 200 means it returned data successfully, so is it something to do on UI?

Comment: Your server log says you have a 200 code for the GET request ? Then yes, it comes from the frontend.

Comment: I also think you don't need  `headers : { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'}`

Comment: Yes server says 200